# Is there a way to avoid using AnyPublisher/eraseToAnyPublisher all over the place?

Tags: swift, combine, opaque-types

I'm just learning how to use Combine. I have experience with Rx (RxSwift and RxJava) and I'm noticing that it's quite similar.

However, one thing that is quite different (and kind of annoying) is that the `Publisher` protocol doesn't use generics for its `Output` and `Failure` types; it uses associated types instead.

What this means is that I can't specify a polymorphic `Publisher` type (such as `Publisher<Int, Error>`) and simply return any type that conforms to `Publisher` with those types. I need to use `AnyPublisher<Int, Error>` instead, and I am forced to include `eraseToAnyPublisher()` all over the place.

If this is the only option, then I'll put up with it. However, I also recently learned about opaque types in Swift, and I'm wondering if I might be able to use them to get around this.

Is there a way for me to have, say, a function that returns `some Publisher` and use specific types for `Output` and `Failure`?

This seems like a perfect case for opaque types, but I can't figure out if there's a way for me to both use an opaque type and specify the associated types.

I'm picturing something like this:

```swift
func createPublisher() -> some Publisher where Output = Int, Failure = Error {
    return Just(1)
}
```

Comment: "it uses associated types instead" That _is_ a generic. That's what a generic protocol _is_.

Comment: Yet “Unlikely” section of the the [generics manifesto](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md#generic-protocols) includes a subsection titled “Generic protocols”, implying that Swift does **not** have generic protocols, and that having an associated type doesn't make a protocol “generic” (in the sense that struct, enum, etc. can be generic).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

### UPDATE

The future is now! If you use Xcode 14.0 beta 2 or later, you can write your `createPublisher` function like this, and it should back-deploy to all systems that support Combine:

```
func createPublisher() -> some Publisher<Int, Never> {
    return Just(1)
}
```

Furthermore, you can use an opaque parameter type to make a function take a generic `Publisher` argument with less syntax and without resorting to an existential or to `AnyPublisher`:

```
func use(_ p: some Publisher<Int, Never>) { }

// means exactly the same as this:

func use<P: Publisher>(_ p: P) where P.Output == Int, P.Failure == Never { }

// and is generally more efficient than either of these:

func use(_ p: any Publisher<Int, Never>) { }
func use(_ p: AnyPublisher<Int, Never>) { }
```

### ORIGINAL

Swift, as of this writing, doesn't have the feature you want. Joe Groff specifically describes what is missing in the section titled “Type-level abstraction is missing for function returns” of his [“Improving the UI of generics” document](https://forums.swift.org/t/improving-the-ui-of-generics/22814/1):

> However, it's common to want to abstract a return type **chosen by the
> implementation** from the caller. For instance, a function may produce
> a collection, but not want to reveal the details of exactly what kind
> of collection it is. This may be because the implementer wants to
> reserve the right to change the collection type in future versions, or
> because the implementation uses composed `lazy` transforms and doesn't
> want to expose a long, brittle, confusing return type in its
> interface. At first, one might try to use an existential in this
> situation:
>
> ```
> func evenValues<C: Collection>(in collection: C) -> Collection where C.Element == Int {
>   return collection.lazy.filter { $0 % 2 == 0 }
> }
> ```
>
> but Swift will tell you today that `Collection` can only be used as a
> generic constraint, leading someone to naturally try this instead:
>
> ```
> func evenValues<C: Collection, Output: Collection>(in collection: C) -> Output
>   where C.Element == Int, Output.Element == Int
> {  
>   return collection.lazy.filter { $0 % 2 == 0 }
> }
> ```
>
> but this doesn't work either, because as noted above, the `Output`
> generic argument is chosen by the caller—this function signature is
> claiming to be able to return *any* kind of collection the caller asks
> for, instead of one specific kind of collection used by the
> implementation.

It's possible that the opaque return type syntax (`some Publisher`) will be extended to support this use someday.

You have three options today. To understand them, let's consider a concrete example. Let's say you want to fetch a text list of integers, one per line, from a URL, and publish each integer as a separate output:

```
return dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
    .mapError { $0 as Error }
    .flatMap { data, response in
        (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode == 200
            ? Result.success(data).publisher
            : Result.failure(URLError(.resourceUnavailable)).publisher
    }
    .compactMap { String(data: $0, encoding: .utf8) }
    .map { data in
        data
            .split(separator: "\n")
            .compactMap { Int($0) }
    }
    .flatMap { $0.publisher.mapError { $0 as Error } }
```

#### Option 1: Spell out the return type

You can use the full, complex return type. It looks like this:

```
extension URLSession {
    func ints(from url: URL) -> Publishers.FlatMap<
        Publishers.MapError<
            Publishers.Sequence<[Int], Never>,
            Error
        >,
        Publishers.CompactMap<
            Publishers.FlatMap<
                Result<Data, Error>.Publisher,
                Publishers.MapError<
                    URLSession.DataTaskPublisher,
                    Error
                >
            >,
            [Int]
        >
    > {
        return dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            ... blah blah blah ...
            .flatMap { $0.publisher.mapError { $0 as Error } }
    }
}
```

I didn't figure out the return type myself. I set the return type to `Int` and then the compiler told me that `Int` is not the correct return type, and the error message included the correct return type. This is not pretty, and if you change the implementation you'll have to figure out the new return type.

#### Option 2: Use `AnyPublisher`

Add `.eraseToAnyPublisher()` to the end of the publisher:

```
extension URLSession {
    func ints(from url: URL) -> AnyPublisher<Int, Error> {
        return dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            ... blah blah blah ...
            .flatMap { $0.publisher.mapError { $0 as Error } }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

This is the common and easy solution, and usually what you want. If you don't like spelling out `eraseToAnyPublisher`, you can write your own `Publisher` extension to do it with a shorter name, like this:

```
extension Publisher {
    var typeErased: AnyPublisher<Output, Failure> { eraseToAnyPublisher() }
}
```

#### Option 3: Write your own `Publisher` type

You can wrap up your publisher in its own type. Your type's `receive(subscriber:)` constructs the “real” publisher and then passes the subscriber to it, like this:

```
extension URLSession {
    func ints(from url: URL) -> IntListPublisher {
        return .init(session: self, url: url)
    }
}

struct IntListPublisher: Publisher {
    typealias Output = Int
    typealias Failure = Error

    let session: URLSession
    let url: URL

    func receive<S: Subscriber>(subscriber: S) where
        S.Failure == Self.Failure, S.Input == Self.Output
    {
        session.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .flatMap { $0.publisher.mapError { $0 as Error } }
            ... blah blah blah ...
            .subscribe(subscriber)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for writing it out, this explanation was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: It is worth noting that in option 1, changing the implementation will almost always change the return type. Thus, if you are vending some API, with option 1, you are essentially guaranteeing that your implementation will stay the same until the next breaking release. This is not the case with the other two solutions.

Comment: Future not quite here yet. The following works...

let c3 = Environment.live.messages.sink { _ in }

But the following does not...

let c4 = Environment.live.messages.map { $0 + "!" }.sink { _ in }

Doesn't help a lot to provide publishers on which one can't use operators.

Comment: @MichaelLong You're right. I've removed the discussion of `any Publisher`.

Answer (score 2):

With opaque return the type is defined by what is exactly returned from closure, so you can use just

```
func createPublisher() -> some Publisher {
    return Just(1)
}

let cancellable = createPublisher()
   .print()
   .sink(receiveCompletion: { _ in
       print(">> done")
   }) { value in
       print(">> \(value)")
   }

// ... all other code here
```

and it works. Tested with Xcode 11.4.

[image: demo]

Comment: What I am asking is if you can treat the return value as a publisher with `Output = Int`, or if you can only treat it as a generic publisher.

Comment: It works but is relatively useless. Try doing `\(value + 1`) and you'll get an error because your publisher's output type isn't visible. You can fix that with `some Publisher<Int, Never>`, which now works... as  long as `createPublisher` only attempts to return a single type.

Answer (score 1):

I had no luck with `some Publisher` (annoying restriction).

One option is to use `AnyPublisher`:

```swift
func a() -> AnyPublisher<(a: Int, b: String), Never> {
    return Just((a: 1, b: "two")).eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

func b() -> AnyPublisher<String, Never> {
    return a().map(\.b).eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

a().sink(receiveValue: {
    let x = $0 // (a: 1, b: "two)
})

b().sink(receiveValue: {
    let x = $0 // "two"
})
```

---

Alternatively, the "Apple way" (what they use in the standard library) seems to be type aliases (or wrapper structs):

```swift
enum PublisherUtils {
    typealias A = Just<(a: Int, b: String)>
    typealias B = Publishers.MapKeyPath<A, String>
    // or implement a simple wrapper struct like what Combine does
}

func a() -> PublisherUtils.A {
    return Just((a: 1, b: "two"))
}

func b() -> PublisherUtils.B {
    return a().map(\.b)
}

a().sink(receiveValue: {
    let x = $0 // (a: 1, b: "two)
})

b().sink(receiveValue: {
    let x = $0 // "two"
})
```

This is the purpose of the `Publishers` namespace in the Combine framework.

Structs are more opaque than type aliases. Type aliases can result in error messages like `Cannot convert Utils.MyTypeAlias (aka 'TheLongUnderlyingTypeOf') to expected type ABC`, so the closest you can get to proper opaque types is probably to use a struct, which is essentially what the `AnyPublisher` is.

Comment: I don't see what the big deal is. This is what AnyPublisher is for, it is the type eraser for Publisher.

Comment: I only brought up the second part because that's what the Combine framework itself does.

Answer (score 0):

A really simple trick that helped us reduce most of the verbosity was basically to create a file with the following :

```
// MARK: Dependencies Extension
typealias SafePublisher<T> = AnyPublisher<T, Never>
typealias IntSafePublisher = SafePublisher<Int>
typealias Int64SafePublisher = SafePublisher<Int64>
typealias Float64SafePublisher = SafePublisher<Float>

// Then for value types, something like

protocol SafePublishing {
    associatedtype SafePublisherType
}

extension SafePublishing {
    typealias SafePublisherType = SafePublisher<Self>
}

struct APublishedType: SafePublishing {
}

// And Magic

var myPublisher: APublishedType.SafePublisherType?

func takeInPublishers(myPubisherVar: APublishedType.SafePublisherType) {
    myPubisherVar
        .sink { myStructType in
            // DO SOMETHING
        }
        .cancel()
}
```