# How to use eraseToAnyPublisher on the output of the Combine merge operator

Tags: swift, xcode, combine

Given this code:

```swift
let a = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()
let b = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()
        
let result = a.merge(with:b).eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

I would think that `result` would have the type `AnyPublisher<Int, Never>`, but instead it looks like Xcode is seeing it as (white-space formatting mine):

```swift
AnyPublisher<
    Publishers.MergeMany<
        PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>
    >.Output,
    Publishers.MergeMany<
        PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>
    >.Failure
> (aka 'AnyPublisher<Int, Never>')
```

And that is *just* not what I expected. I guess there's some implementation being hidden, but it's not nearly what I'd hope for. And clearly, given the "aka" part, there's some acknowledgment that Xcode knows that it's equivalent to 'AnyPublisher<Int, Never>', but why isn't it type-erased to that, entirely?

I even tried type-erasing earlier in the chain, like so:

```swift
let a = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>().eraseToAnyPublisher()
let b = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>().eraseToAnyPublisher()
        
let result = a.merge(with:b).eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

And that's only slightly better, as Xcode thinks `result` has type:

```swift
AnyPublisher<
    Publishers.MergeMany<
        AnyPublisher<Int, Never>
    >.Output,
    Publishers.MergeMany<
        AnyPublisher<Int, Never>
    >.Failure
> (aka 'AnyPublisher<Int, Never>')
```

Comment: Today when I run your code on Xcode 14.3, it's your answer - AnyPublisher<Int, Never>

Comment: I retried today on Xcode 14.3.1 and the problem persists. I am option-clicking on result to see what Xcode thinks. What did you do to see AnyPublisher<Int, Never>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because [`eraseToAnyPublisher`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publishers/mergemany/erasetoanypublisher()) is declared as:

```
func eraseToAnyPublisher() -> AnyPublisher<Self.Output, Self.Failure>
```

In your case, `Self` is the type `Publishers.MergeMany<PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>>>`, as that is what `merge` returns. After a simple substitution, replacing `Self` with the type that `merge` returns, the return type of `eraseToAnyPublisher` becomes:

```
AnyPublisher<
    Publishers.MergeMany<PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>>.Output,
    Publishers.MergeMany<PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>>.Failure
>
```

Of course, if you follow through all the type aliases, this is the same type as `AnyPublisher<Int, Never>`.

Xcode *could* have been designed to only show the "aka" type, i.e. the type after all the type aliases have been resolved, but that kind of goes against the whole point of type aliases, which is that the type *should be called by another name*. If I have:

```
typealias Money = Decimal
func deposit(amount: Money) { ... }
```

I certainly do not want this function to show up in Xcode *only* as `deposit(amount: Decimal)`!

Side note: you can also cast to an existential type [as an alternative to `eraseToAnyPublisher`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61579804/5133585).

```
a.merge(with:b) as any Publisher<Int, Never>
```

Calling `eraseToAnyPublisher` on the above will actually give you a "short" type name, but there really is no point :)

Comment: Thank you! That indirectly answers my question, and I will accept it as the correct solution because of the good explanations. In my particular situation, I actually found that assigning the result as is (ie even without the `as` cast operation) to a var declared as AnyPublisher<Int, Never> worked fine and hid my implementation.

Comment: For the sake of discussion, though, I would posit that the behaviour I was looking for was the behaviour that most people would expect. It might be true that the implementation leads to the behaviour we're seeing in an expected way, but the end-result is not ideal. It would be better if a different mechanism were pursued to get the better result. For instance, if eraseToAnyPublisher could be defined as `func eraseToAnyPublisher() -> AnyPublisher<Expanded(Self.Output), Expanded(Self.Failure)>' where by Expanded, I mean that the Self.* expressions should be replaced with what they refer to.

Comment: @CuriousJorge Sure, it is certainly possible to add such a feature into swift and Xcode, but alas, we have limited time and unlimited desires, so Apple chooses the ones that matters more to implement first. Adding a new language feature just to fix a little display inconvenience, and also considering that `any Publisher` has been implemented, I think it is highly unlikely that they would add such a thing.

Comment: If there's an existing workaround, I would certainly understand that. Could you explain how to use Any Publisher vs AnyPublisher? And is the cast to Any Publisher really only available on iOS? What is the workaround for that?

Comment: @CuriousJorge I think we are slightly going a bit off topic here... I am not aware of any functional differences between `any Publisher` and `AnyPublisher`, but I might be wrong. And sorry, apparently my Xcode's documentation is outdated. `any Publisher<Int, Never>` is available on all platforms :)

Comment: Thanks for all the links and the updates! I hope Apple eventually finds some way to just have eraseToAnyPublisher simply do what we hope for. But in the meantime, I can use the cast, or encapsulate that in a function as described in the link you gave. All good here!